# Passing a Context Variable Into URL Argument

Tags: python, django

I want to dynamically generate a link that resembles something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'my_app.views.page1' %}">
```

The variable of the view I want is contained in the context variable `nextURL`. So I've created a statement that looks like this:

```
<a href="{% url '{{ nextURL }}' %}">
```

But that leads to this error:

```
Reverse for '{{ nextURL }}' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Taking out the quotes around `{{ nextURL }}` produces similar results. Is there any way to do this? I don't want to hardcode the link to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply `<a href="{% url nextURL %}">`.